# Physics messed up with cardboard scene in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, vuforia, google-cardboard, particle-system

I am in the process of putting together an app using the Google Cardboard SDK. The user will be able to use the app with or without cardboard. So, there is a switch button inside the app, that activates and deactivates stereo rendering.

The app also uses the Vuforia SDK to track image targets. If a specific target is recognized, some 3D objects above the target and a particle system starts to emit particles.

Everything works fine in non-stereo mode. Particles are emitted and falling correctly as intended. They should simulate snow. Also if the user turns the image target to an angle, the 3D objects above fall down.

When switching to stereo mode, the physics are messed up completely. The snow particles are not falling anymore, they seem to "teleport" around the screen. Also the 3D objects do fall upwards, with a really heavy negative gravity. Timescale seems multiplied several times, but is not - I double checked that. Gravity also does not change when switching between non-stereo and stereo rendering.

Everything works fine in Unity Editor in moth modes. It only appears on the device, which is an iPhone 5.

- Cardboard SDK is version 0.52, which is the newest.
- Unity is version 5.3.1.
- <strike>Vuforia is 5.0.6, which is not the newest, but release notes do not indicate a fix concerning physics. Will update it anyway as a next step.</strike>
- Vuforia is 5.0.10, which is the latest version.

I double checked gravity and timescale, which are not changing when switching between modes. I have a hard time figuring out what might cause the physics to mess up.

## EDIT:

I did some further investigations. I made me a little gizmo sitting always in front of the camera but getting the rotation of the Unity world space axes, so I know the 3D-world is oriented in relation to the camera. And it turns out, that when in VR mode with the Google cardboard camera system, the world does spin around the camera heavily. I managed to hold the test device in a way, so it is slowing down and almost freezing, but I have no explanation for the effect yet.

Comment: This question is incorrectly tagged -- use [unity3d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) instead of [unity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity)

Comment: @PetterHesselberg Sorry, my bad.

Comment: Do you use some screen to world coordinate transformations?

Comment: @Denis Not that I am aware of. But I did find out somethings else and edited my question.

Comment: Is the user able to move or look around by moving the device? I would add a UI text on screen and log there the different accelerometer and gyroscope values, I think they might return some strange values.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my setup right again. Unfortunately I did not find the source of the weird behavior. But By deleting the Vuforia Prefab and the Cardboard Prefab and adding them again to the scene, the problem was solved.